# Combination of linear functions that give the derivative operator

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

> Let $D$ be the derivative operator and $C^\infty$ the set of functions
>   derivable infinitely many times.
>
> Here $f^n=f\circ f\circ\cdots\circ f\text{, }n\text{ times}$

It can be easily shown that there exists no linear function $f\in\mathcal{L}(C^\infty)$  such that $f^2=D$.

If I am not wrong, this can be easily extended to the non existence of a function $f\in\mathcal{L}(C^\infty)$ such that $\prod f=D$ as a finite product.

What can be said for an infinite product? How can one (dis)approve of the existence of a linear function $f\in\mathcal{L}(C^\infty)$ such that $f^n=D$ ?

It seems unlikely to me, but I have found no way to prove it.

Comment: This is very confused.  By "product" you mean composition of linear functions, right?  This is already unclear because $D$ is not a function from $D_1$ to $D_1$ but from $D_1$ to something larger, so it's impossible for a composition of functions from $D_1$ to $D_1$ to give $D$, no matter what.  Next, assuming this is fixed: do you want all your functions $f_i$ to be the same?  If not, just take one to be $D$ and all the others to be the identity, and the answer is trivial.  So maybe you want them all to be equal? (continued)

Comment: (continued) Now even if we fix my previous objections by replacing $D_1$ by $C^\infty$ (or something) and demanding all functions $f_i$ to be equal, the question is now what is this infinite product of which you speak. If it is $f^\infty$ defined as some kind of limit of $f^i$ for $i\to+\infty$ for some topology which you didn't explain, then presumably one will have $f^\infty\circ f^\infty = f^\infty$ by continuity of composition, so that would imply $D\circ D=D$ which is not the case.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Thank you, i didn't notice all of that. I changed $D_1$ to $C^\infty$. However, isn't the notion of 'infinite product' as $\prod\limits_{i=1}^\infty f_i=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\prod\limits_{i=1}^n f_i$ defined ? (I truly don't know, my initial question was just something that was interesting me though I have no real expertise in this field at all). I also added the _each one different from D_ in the 2nd case.

Comment: "Each one different from $D$" doesn't change anything: now simply take one $f_i$ to be $-D$, one to be $-1$ and all others to be $1$ (where $1$ is the identity, of course).  There is simply too much freedom in a product (even finite) unless you demand something like that all factors be equal.  Apart from that, an infinite product may be defined as you suggest… provided we have a topology with which to define the limit, and there are many topologies on the set of linear operators on $C^\infty$ functions.

Comment: Also, the notation $\prod$ should be avoided for noncommutative products because it does not make clear what the order of the operations is.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I removed the 2nd part and only left the one where $f$ is unique. What should I use instead of $\prod$ ?

Comment: Instead of $\prod_{i=1}^n f_i$ you should write "$f_1\cdots f_n$" which makes the order clear. But since now you restricted yourself to a constant product, just write "$f^n$", and for the infinite case, write "$f^\infty := \lim_{n\to+\infty} f^n$ assuming it exists" (but you would still have to clarify the topology).  But anyway, I already answered this: $f^\infty\cdot f^\infty$ will be $\lim_{n\to+\infty} f^{2n} = f^\infty$ for any reasonable definition of limit, and since $D$ does not satisfy $D^2 = D$, it cannot be $f^\infty$, which I think answers your question.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen It indeed does, could you add this as an answer ?

Answer (score -1):

Not claiming to understand the main question of the "infinite product", I could comment on the title and the linear non-existence claim. [Fractional derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) is a linear operator, where one could write $D^{\frac{1}{2}}$ as a functional square root of the differentiation operator that when applied twice to a function will have the same effect as differentiation. (see further, e.g., the "Short Introduction to Fractional Calculus").

Comment: Then, could you please tell me where my proof is wrong ?

Let's suppose that there exists $f\in\mathcal{L}(C_\infty)$ such that $f(f)=D$.

We can see that $\ker f\subset Co$ where $Co$ is the set of constant functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore, as a vector space, $\ker f=Co$ or $\ker f=\{0\}$.

Suppose that $\ker f=Co$. Let $a$ be an function with a non zero constant derivative. Then $f(a)'=f(f(f(a)))=f(a')=0$ hence $f(a)\subset Co$ thus $f(f(a))=0$ which is absurd.

If $\ker f=\{0\}$ then it's absurd (Let $a$ be a non zero constant function. $f(f(a))=0\Rightarrow a=0$).

QED ?

Comment: * meant $f(a)\in Co$ of course

Comment: http://prntscr.com/4fnpc7 It doesn't really look like a $C^\infty\rightarrow C^\infty$ operator to me ...